# Boshes damages for a מלבין פני חברו ברבים

Tags: money, derech-eretz-manners, torts-damages

Asked by my kid (albeit less fleshed-out than the way I'm presenting it here):

One should rather submit himself to be burned alive than cause another to blanch in shame in public, according to [*Sota* 10:2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2373&size=1). *Tosafos* there seem to take it as halachic fact, but, even if not, it seems at the very least to be a moral equivalence: causing another public shame is on a par with being burned alive. (Imagine how bad being shamed publicly must be!)

How then — at least in a case of an act of *nezek* that occurred in public — can the courts possibly evaluate *boshes*, the monetary damages for embarrassment, as some finite amount of money? It would seem it should be an inestimably large sum of money: the act committed by the tortfeasor is as bad as being burned alive!

Comment: הכל לפי המבייש והמתבייש Could the mishna have been any clearer? :)

Comment: Doesn't the Torah give us fixed prices for people being killed?

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's how they evaluate it. The question is how the amount of many can be finite, or anything less than extraordinarily large. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @msh210 I was being sarcastic. Edit if you want, but I did understand the intention. I'm just pointing out how vague the mishna is about this.

Comment: @avi, _kofer_ is, if I'm not mistaken, the value of the person (as a slave). So in any case of _halbanas p'ne chavero barabim_ (which is also a tort) the _boshes_ should be precisely the full value of the injured party (or perhaps of the tortfeasor, since he's the one who should have been burned alive)?

Comment: By the way, it doesn't literally mean that it is as if he kills him. For example, embarassing someone is not yehareg ve'al yaavor. See Shu"T Bnei Banim pt. 1 siman 41 (or use the easy way and look at [Piskei Bnei Banim](http://www.aishdas.org/articles/PiskeiBneiBanim.pdf)).

Comment: @ba "even if not, it seems at the very least to be a moral equivalence" (a quotation from the question).

Comment: The question can be made even stronger: not only should one jump into a furnace in this world to avoid shaming someone else, but the Gemara in HaZahav (BM 58b) says that one's stay in Gehennom is extended beyond the usual 12 months if he/she embarrasses someone else in public. (The other two on that list are calling someone by a name they dislike even if they don't respond to it, and eishes ish.)

Answer (score 2):

In theory maybe you are right. The concept of paying the full value of someone's life certainly exists - as is the case by kofer (when one's mu'ad animal kills a person). So your kid's point is not merely rhetorical. In practice of course we have to judge based on exactly how much the person was actually shamed, but I don't see why it can't be possible that in certain cases one would indeed be required to pay an extremely large amount of money.